# A manga where a the female lead died by her step sister and is reincarnated a year back

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

At the start the female lead is caged and is being forced by a masked man and later she is killed by step sister who throws her off a cliff. After this she wakes up yo find herself a year back in time where she now remembers that she has to get married to her husband (heir to lin/li family) of last time and not make the same mistake. The husband has a small kid. She ends up marrying the guy and loves his son as her own, but her father and step mother and step sister are always tormenting her. She even has a brother who is good in music and helps her and loves her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is "lin/li family?"  When and where did you read this?  Do you recall the name of any of the characters or locations?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it! It's ***[Never Let Go of My Ex-Husband](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/never-let-go-of-my-ex-husband)***.

> Shi Weiyi, the second elder daughter of the Shi family, abandoned her husband and stepson and ran away with another wicked man, but was in the end murdered by the wicked man and her half sister. When she came to her senses again, she found herself reincarnated and had a vague memory of being locked up by a silver-masked man. Who is this silver-mask? How was she murdered in her previous life? Why couldn't she like her stepson and who is his mother? In this life, she will figure these all out and seek her own vengence.